# Deploy Rails 3 site using AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-web-services

I am going to be deploying a site i have built in rails 3 for the first time.. It has been recommended that I use AWS. I have read through some tutorials online but keep running into the same problem. When i run the command

```
    rails g vulcanize complete_passenger_mysql
```

I get the following error message

```
    Could not find generator vulcanize.
```

At first glance it seems as if rails 3.1 is not compatible with the Gem: rubber.

has any one else had the same issue or knows of any way of doing this?. I am also willing to listen to alternative options, i chose AWS as it is free to start off with and people recommended it. Any suggestions welcome.. I would really like to deploy my site soon

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the rubber gem to your gemfile ?

Comment: Thought i had, just added and the script ran..Such a rookie mistake :), thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the rubber to your Gemfile in order for its generators to be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a rubber vulcanize:

```
rubber vulcanize complete_passenger_mysql
```