# Cannot deploy to AWS EC2 with Rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rubber

I am following [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2), but when I run

```
rails g vulcanize complete_passenger_mysql
```

I get

```
Could not find generator vulcanize.
```

I also found [this thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040986/deploy-rails-3-site-using-aws), but again, without any success.

The version of installed rubber is **2.2.4**, ruby **ruby 1.9.3p385**, rails **Rails 3.2.12**.

I spent the whole afternoon of figuring this issue out, but I stuck here.
I would be grateful for every advice,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you cannot rails g vulcanize is because you are supposed to do rubber vulcanize.

```
rubber vulcanize complete_passenger_mysql
```

That should get you going...